# Is my understanding of how a stack works correct?

Tags: stack

Just want confirm my understanding of the stack structure's push/pop operations.  Say you have a sequence of operations -- `push(1), push(2), pop, push(1), push(2), pop, pop, pop, push(2), pop` that are performed on a stack.  The sequence of popped out values are `2, 2, 1, 1, 2`.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: The push-pop of the stack look like this]

Yep, your popped sequence is correct.